# Joomla 2.5 all links show the home page

Tags: joomla

I have joomla 2.5 it show many error.

1. All links even error page also showing home page.
2. Error message 'Unable to move file' when install extension.
3. Can't rewrite configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

You've got server configuration/setup/permission problems, I'm surprised you didn't get any warnings when installing Joomla.  I'd start by looking very carefully at http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html, and seeing what is missing or is different on your server/host.  Once that is done (and configuration writability will be the first clue), Joomla will be able to behave as it should.  Though, you may very well have to re-install, as some steps may not have been able to complete properly due to your permissions.